# Can we club multiple generic class based views in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I want to display a list of items and also a form to add further items at the end of the list. Hence I was thinking of creating a view as something below:

I have come across a class called ListCreateAPIView but I don't want to use django rest framework.

Please let me know your suggestions if and how can I club two generic class based view and how the path in urls.py would look like.

Further how should we refer to the list and create form objects in 'listnadd_task.html'?

```
<views.py>

from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from .models import Task
from .forms import CreateTask


class ListAndAddView(ListView, CreateView)
    model = Task
    form_class = CreateTask
    context_object_name = 'listnadd_task'
    
    ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "club"?

Comment: I mean merge two or more 'generic class based view' into one custom view.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, that I want to have one view which helps me to display the list of item as well as add the new item at the very end. @Chris Please let me know if I am approaching the problem in the wrong way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're approaching the problem the wrong way or not. I was just confused by that language. Maybe "combine" would be clearer?

Comment: @Chris yes. Basically I would like to combine the functionality of class 'ListView' and class 'CreateView' into one view